# Upper Bound and Supremum definition

Tags: calculus

I am reading a Calculus book by Zill and Wright but I think it has some mistakes:

They define for a set of reals A an upper bound $x$ as a number such that for every $a \in A$, $a < x$. So for instance $(0,1]$ has an upper bound namely every $1 < x$.

Then they define the supremum of $A$ as a number $x$ such that $x$ is an upper bound of $A$ and for that every other upper bound $y$ then $x \leq y$.

But then $(0,1]$ has an upper bound but no supremum since for every upper bound $x$ I can always find $c$ such that $x-c$ is still an upper bound, but this contradicts the fact that every set with an upper bound has a supremum.

Am i missing something?

Comment: $(0,1]$ has a supremum, namely $1$, since $1-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound.

Comment: Are you sure they write "...for every $a \in A, a < x$" and not "...for every $a \in A, a \leq x$"?

Comment: According to the book's definition $1$ is not a supremum since is not even an upper bound. Yes I am completely sure they wrote $a < x$. I guess then it's just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Usually we say "$x$ is an upper bound for $A$" if for all $y\in A$, $x \ge y$. This stands in contrast to your quoted definition, which uses $>$ rather than $\ge$. Given what your text goes on to say about supremums, it seems likely this difference is a simple mistake.